# Liquibase database lock discrepancy

Tags: liquibase

I'm having this weird issue with the database lock in Liquibase 4.23

I have a container to execute some changelog to an Oracle SQL server that runs fine. I was testing out something with the execute-sql function after to show the databasechangeloglock but I see that the query result shows that there is still a lock, but list-locks as well directly querying the table shows there is no lock.

Have anyone noticed this issue before? I am thinking it might be some issue with the timestamp since the lockgranted column is 1 hour ahead of the container (sql server timestamp is in +1:00 but container is UTC).

Thanks.

Tried:

1. liquibase.sh execute-sql --sql="select count(*) from databasechangeloglock where LOCKED=0" returns 0
2. liquibase.sh list-locks returns "No locks"
3. Query in sqlplus returns 1

Expected:
Command should return query with count of 1